# Match phrase query with multiple fields in elasticsearch using nest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, match-phrase

I am trying to query using matchphrase but on multiple fields but my nest allows me to do it on only one field here's my code snippet

```cs
    var result = client.Search<document>(s => s
    .Analyzer("automplete")
    .Query(p => p
    .MatchPhrase(M => M
    .OnField("description")
    .Query(value))));
```

I have multiple fields in class documents and I want search on that fields too.

Please help me with this - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`match_phrase`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html) does not even support multiple fields. For using a `match` query over multiple fields, you need to use [`multi_match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) query.

```
var result = client.Search<document>(s => s
    .Analyzer("automplete")
    .Query(p => p
        .MultiMatch(m => m
            .OnFields(new[] { "description" /*, add other fields here */ })
            .Query(value)
            .Type(TextQueryType.Phrase))));
```

Comment: @bittusarkar: thanks for the answer.. It helped me a lot.. And one more question. How can I initialize `var result` before hand just like we do `string  result = string.empty`. Can I do the same for elasticsearch ?? TIA :)

Comment: @ASN I did not understand your question. What would you want to do that anyway? You can always initialize it with `null`.

Comment: How can I initialize var response before hand just like we do `string result = string.empty`. Can I do the same for elasticsearch ??

Generally we use `var response= client.search<className>(//some code here);`
Instead of that i want to initialize `response` first and then use the parameter later in the code.

I hope you understood now or else I can mail you if you can share your mail id.

Comment: I want to write a if else condition which takes two different queries, but the processing of result is same after the response is obtained. so wanted to initialize it before if-else loop. I tried initializing it with null and it threw error as we are equating it with search response after initialization. So I initialized using `var response = (ISearchResponse<className>)null;`. This served the purpose. Thanks. Your answer gave me an idea. :)

Comment: Oh, don't use `var` in this case. A simple `ISearchResponse<className> response = null;` should be good enough :)